# "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute" array

Tags: python, class-method

This should be a softball question.

I have a custom class called Table with methods including getTableName

```
class table(object):
    def __init__(self, tableName, aliasName = 'none'):
        """Create assign a name"""
        self.tableName = tableName
        if aliasName == 'none':
            self.aliasName = tableName
        else:
            self.aliasName = aliasName
        self.columns = []
        self.relatedTables = []
    def getTableName (self):
        return self.tableName
```

In a separate script I created an array of tables

```
import table
tables = []
```

Then I append the tables array.

```
def appendTables(newTable):
    #check list of tables for match

    #if first batch of tables just append to tables
    if len(tables) == 0:
        tables.append(newTable)
        return
    found = False
    for oTable in tables:
        print "type newTable"  #type newTable
        print type(newTable)   #<class 'table.table'>
        print "type oTable"    #type oTable
        print type (oTable)    #<type 'module'>
        a = newTable.getTableName()  #OK
        b = oTable.getTableName()   #CRASH "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getTableName'"
```

Why does Python not recognize the class?

Comment: I think this conflicts with the module name. What is this module/package called ? Try using a different local variable. Example: `for t in tables:`

Answer (score 2):

If the class `table` is defined in the file `table.py`, you need either

```
from table import table
```

or use `table.table` for the name of the class. Also, user-defined class names should, by convention, start with a capital letter, so that your code would look like

```
class Table(object):
```

and

```
from table import Table
```

and

```
table.Table
```